# "Unable to fetch mapping. Do you have indices matching the pattern?" Kibana error

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm getting this error when I run kibana on localhost, port 5601. Followed all steps during installation to the T. Also, when I start the server on port 5601, I get an error message saying "Port 5601 is already in use", whereas when I use it on some other port, say 5600, it runs fine. The indexing error is still there though. Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: When do you get the message? When opening it in a browser or during start-up. Are you sure no other cabin process is still running? What OS are you using?

Comment: When I open the browser to localhost:5601. And I'm running ubuntu gnome 14.04

Comment: I would first try to find the process that is keeping port 5601 using something like netstat or ps -ef. Than the kibana error is probably the result of a wrong configured index pattern. Dit you create a pattern in the settings  tab. Usually there is a button on the home screen telling you to configure an index pattern first. Could be something like logstash-*.

Comment: Maybe you can attach a screen dumb to you question, makes it easier for people to help you.